# Duplicate Name in Excel sheet - (wrong formula)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet with several columns, containing a Name in the first cell, and then different values in the other cells.

Example:-

```
John Smith    65  40  30  30  50
Paul White    80  20  50  90  10
Karen Gill    75  34  16  19  88
Norman Black  85  10  40  43  25
Peter Smith   44  40  33  12  50
(etc........)
```

Now I am trying to order these by the top 5 in every cell, and display them with Name and Value.  I am doing something like this at the moment:-

```
=INDEX(DefC!A$4:A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefC!Y$4:Y$150,1),DefC!Y$4:Y$150,0))
=INDEX(DefC!A$4:A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefC!Y$4:Y$150,2),DefC!Y$4:Y$150,0))
=INDEX(DefC!A$4:A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefC!Y$4:Y$150,3),DefC!Y$4:Y$150,0))
=INDEX(DefC!A$4:A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefC!Y$4:Y$150,4),DefC!Y$4:Y$150,0))
=INDEX(DefC!A$4:A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefC!Y$4:Y$150,5),DefC!Y$4:Y$150,0))
```

This works perfectly, however, if I have the same value, I am getting the same name, instead of different names.  If I take my example, I have 40 and 50 in row 1 and row 5.  So at the moment for the second row of values I would get :-

```
John Smith    40
John Smith    40  
Karen Gill    34
Paul White    20
Norman Black  10
```

instead of :-

```
John Smith    40
Peter Smith    40  
Karen Gill    34
Paul White    20
Norman Black  10
```

Can I do it any other way so that I can get the "second" name if the value is the same, instead of the same name?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Which version of excel do you use? If you have `Excel 365` then it would be easier to get desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(LARGE($C$2:$C$6,ROW()-1),$C$2:$C$6*(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE($K$1:K1)<>$A$2:$A$6),ROW($K$1:K1)^0)>ROW()-2),0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

---

MY SOLUTION

Tried this but getting the same results.

At the moment I have the following :-

```
=INDEX(DefWing!A$4:A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefWing!O$4:O$150,1),DefWing!O$4:O$150,0))
=INDEX(DefWing!A$4:A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefWing!O$4:O$150,2),DefWing!O$4:O$150,0))
=INDEX(DefWing!A$4:A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefWing!O$4:O$150,3),DefWing!O$4:O$150,0))
=INDEX(DefWing!A$4:A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefWing!O$4:O$150,4),DefWing!O$4:O$150,0))
=INDEX(DefWing!A$4:A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefWing!O$4:O$150,5),DefWing!O$4:O$150,0))
```

with your solution I have this now :-

```
=INDEX(DefWing!$A$4:$A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefWing!$O$4:$O$150,ROW()-1),DefWing!$O$4:$O$150*(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(DefWing!$E$1:E1)<>DefWing!$A$4:$A$150),ROW(DefWing!$E$1:E1)^0)>ROW()-2),0))
=INDEX(DefWing!$A$4:$A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefWing!$O$4:$O$150,ROW()-1),DefWing!$O$4:$O$150*(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(DefWing!$E$1:E2)<>DefWing!$A$4:$A$150),ROW(DefWing!$E$1:E2)^0)>ROW()-2),0))
=INDEX(DefWing!$A$4:$A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefWing!$O$4:$O$150,ROW()-1),DefWing!$O$4:$O$150*(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(DefWing!$E$1:E3)<>DefWing!$A$4:$A$150),ROW(DefWing!$E$1:E3)^0)>ROW()-2),0))
=INDEX(DefWing!$A$4:$A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefWing!$O$4:$O$150,ROW()-1),DefWing!$O$4:$O$150*(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(DefWing!$E$1:E4)<>DefWing!$A$4:$A$150),ROW(DefWing!$E$1:E4)^0)>ROW()-2),0))
=INDEX(DefWing!$A$4:$A$150,MATCH(LARGE(DefWing!$O$4:$O$150,ROW()-1),DefWing!$O$4:$O$150*(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(DefWing!$E$1:E5)<>DefWing!$A$4:$A$150),ROW(DefWing!$E$1:E5)^0)>ROW()-2),0))
```

but I am still getting duplicate names

I also tried your solution on a new sheet

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(LARGE($C$2:$C$6,ROW()-1),$C$2:$C$6*(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE($H$1:H1)<>$A$2:$A$6),ROW($H$1:H1)^0)>ROW()-2),0))
```

The first row works, however the next is throwing an error:-

[image: excel problem]

Comment: I added my comments @basic hope you don't mind.  Still not working for me though

Comment: @JMon as I wrote, this is array formula. Use ```Ctrl+Shift+Enter```

Comment: so I insert it in the line near fx and hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter right?  For every cell?  First one works fine, the rest gives me that error.  Do I need to change the formula for the second row?

Comment: ok I get it know, the sample worksheet is working!  But I still have the problem with my main one

Comment: You can enter it into first cell, then copy/paste to other cells. I changed k-argument in ```LARGE``` function from ```1``` to ```ROW()-1```. If your formula doesn't start from 2 row (but perhaps from 4), you must change it accordingly, as well as ```MMULT(...)>ROW()-2```

Comment: I have created a sample sheet with my problem can I attach it somewhere or send it to you?

Comment: never mind I found my issue on the sample sheet, I will need to find on original

Answer (score 0):

You need a tiebreaker. That means that you can't sort on column Y. Add a column with a formula, say column AY. Then apply the LARGE function to column AY. Personally, I wouldn't select a column that's far from the action because it adds the intervening columns to the UsedRange. I would use column Z and hide it.

The way to create a tiebreaker is to modify the original value in such a way that it doesn't make a logical difference but renders the values different from each other. In your case, for example, 40 and 40.001 are logically identical but different to the LARGE function. Therefore your column AY or Z could contain this function.

```
=Y4+(Row()/1000)
```

That would add between 0.004 and 0.150 to the numbers in column Y. You can increase the divisor if you needed. This system would rank equals by their position on the list because 40.04 would rank before 40.150.

Another suggestion is to use the name.

```
=Y4+(CODE(A4)/1000)
```

This would rank "John" before "Peter" but wouldn't break the tie between "John" and "James". With a mere 150 names, you might take several letters into consideration, such as the first three, at the cost of a slightly longer formula.